# Exclusive gestures in SwiftUI when gestures not in the same hierarchy

Tags: ios, swiftui

Basically I would like this to work:

```
struct TestView: View {

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text("Should work simultaneously").onTapGesture {
            print("Work simultaneously")
        }
        Text("Should work simultaneously").onTapGesture {
            print("Work simultaneously")
        }
        Text("Should be exclusive").onTapGesture {
            print("Work exclusively")
        }
    }
    .simultaneousGesture(
        TapGesture().onEnded {
            print("Should work everywhere except for 3th child view")
        }
    )
}
```

}

The `VStack` has a gesture that should always be recognized, except when one their childs wants to handle the touches exclusively.

The pasted code is a minimal example.

In my real project, the 3th child view is a custom `DatePicker` that appears on some condition. I would like to dismiss the picker when one clicks outside, but if one clicks inside the picker it shouldn't be dismissed yet. For this reason I need handle the touches in the picker exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

You can't block up the view hierarchy, only down. In order to have the simultaneous gesture on only part of the `VStack`, you will need to separate those views into their own composed view with the `.simultaneousGesture()` on that view. Presuming you don't want to change the look of your view, I would simply wrap the subviews you want the `.simultaneousGesture()` on in a `Group{}`. Something like this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Text("Should work simultaneously").onTapGesture {
                    print("Work simultaneously")
                }
                Text("Should work simultaneously").onTapGesture {
                    print("Work simultaneously")
                }
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(
                TapGesture().onEnded {
                    print("Should work everywhere except for 3th child view")
                }
            )

            Text("Should be exclusive")
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Work exclusively")
                }
        }
    }
}
```